# Using the ordering locale with partial maps

Tags: isabelle, partial-ordering

The following code doesn't typecheck:

```
type_synonym env = "char list ⇀ val"

interpretation map: order "op ⊆⇩m :: (env ⇒ env ⇒ bool)" "(λa b. a ≠ b ∧ a ⊆⇩m b)"
by unfold_locales (auto intro: map_le_trans simp: map_le_antisym)

lemma
  assumes "mono (f :: env ⇒ env)"
  shows "True"
by simp
```

Isabelle complains with the following error at the lemma:

```
Type unification failed: No type arity option :: order

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  mono :: (??'a ⇒ ??'b) ⇒ bool
Operand:   f :: (char list ⇒ val option) ⇒ char list ⇒ val option
```

Why so? Did I miss something to use the interpretation? I suspect I need something like a newtype wrapper here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you interpret a locale like `order` which corresponds to a type class, you only get the theorems proved inside the context of the locale. However, the constant `mono` is only defined on the type class. The reason is that `mono`'s type contains two type variables, whereas only one is available inside locales from type classes. You can notice this because there is no `map.mono` stemming from your interpretation.

If you instantiate the type class `order` for the option type with `None` being less than `Some x`, then you can use `mono` for maps, because the function space instantiates `order` with the pointwise order. However, the ordering `<=` on maps will only be semantically equivalent to `⊆⇩m`, not syntactically, so none of the existing theorems about `⊆⇩m` will work for `<=` and vice versa. Moreover, your theories will be incompatible with other people's that instantiate `order` for `option` differently.

Therefore, I recommend to go without type classes. The predicate `monotone` explicitly takes the order to be used. This is a bit more writing, but in the end, you are more flexible than with type classes. For example, you can write `monotone (op ⊆⇩m) (op ⊆⇩m) f` to express that `f` is a monotone transformation of environments.